The widget background is incorrectly overlaid in Qt when using QChartView
I couldn't figure out why my background is not displayed correctly when I add QChartView to my main widget.
MainWindow::MainWindow( QWidget* parent, Qt::WindowFlags f) : QWidget(parent, f)
{


    setBackgroundImage(":/4015db3053c401bf5c6d3eef84d7c583.jpg");
    series = new QPieSeries();
    initializeCategories();
    updateChartSeries();
    QChart* chart = new QChart();
    chart->addSeries(series);
    chart->legend()->hide();
    chart->setBackgroundBrush(Qt::NoBrush);
    chart->setPlotAreaBackgroundVisible(false);


    /*QChartView* chartView = new QChartView(chart);
    chartView->setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QColor(255, 255, 255, 0)));
    chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    chartView->setParent(this);
    chartView->setGeometry(-5, 50, 600, 400);*/

    
    gridLayout.setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    //layout->setGeometry();
    QWidget* container = new QWidget(this);
    container->setLayout(&gridLayout);
    container->setGeometry(0, 25, 650, 100);


    QPushButton* btn = new QPushButton("Add expense", this);
    btn->setGeometry(200, 420, 200, 100);
    btn->setStyleSheet("background-color: #ED2442; color: white; font-weight: bold; font: 14pt");
    connect(btn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::addExpenses);
        
}
void MainWindow::setBackgroundImage(const QString& imagePath)
{
    QPixmap bkgnd(imagePath);

    bkgnd = bkgnd.scaled(this->size(), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);

    QPalette palette;
    palette.setBrush(QPalette::Window, bkgnd);
    this->setPalette(palette);
    this->setAutoFillBackground(true);
}


How is the background displayed when there is a QChartView

How is the background displayed when QChartView is commented out


From the QWidget::palette docs: "QWidget propagates explicit palette roles from parent to child. If you assign a brush or color to a specific role on a palette and assign that palette to a widget, that role will propagate to all the widget's children, overriding any system defaults for that role." So, don't use it for that. Override the paintEvent() of the main window and draw that background on your own using QPainter, either by painting the pixmap, or by using QBrush, if it's tiled.
